# API JSON response is blank

Tags: python, json, api, flask

My goal is to consume an API I am using from Financialmodelingprep.com using flask to run my python program. I created a route and defined a function as described in the documentation. The only edit I made was passing the stock symbol as a parameter into the function so that when I hit the endpoint with the stock symbol it will display the symbols' data in a JSON object the browser.

When I run the program and hit the endpoint I get a 200 response in the anaconda terminal but the browser just shows an empty JSON response like so: {}

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import json


#instatiating the Flask Class. "__name__" references the name of the current module being worked with which is hello-world.py
app = Flask(__name__)

# Instaniating a routeRoute
@app.route('/stock/profile/<string:symbol>')
def get_jsonparsed_data(symbol):

    """
    Receive the content of ``url``, parse it as JSON and return the object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str

    Returns
    -------
    dict
    """
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

symbol=None
url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/{}?apikey=myapikeywashere".format(symbol)
```

Comment: Have you checked what the URL gives to you e.g. if you put it directly to your web browser address bar?

Comment: Yes, and I love the way it works but the point of me using the API URL is to use it on my own application. I'm building a micro-services architecture and this API would help me fulfill one micro-service.

Comment: Can you edit the question and demostrate that you have checked the API URL gives you a desired response in a manner that readers can verify how it works or is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

To use the API to get stock information on a google stock (GOOG) one would normally use the following: 
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/GOOG?apikey=yourApiKeyWouldGoHere

And the response would be:

```
{
  "symbol" : "GOOG",
  "profile" : {
    "price" : 1410.42,
    "beta" : "1.022765",
    "volAvg" : "2447698",
    "mktCap" : "9.6415757E11",
    "lastDiv" : "0",
    "range" : "1013.536-1532.106",
    "changes" : 7.62,
    "changesPercentage" : "(+0.54%)",
    "companyName" : "Alphabet Inc.",
    "exchange" : "Nasdaq Global Select",
    "industry" : "Online Media",
    "website" : "https://www.abc.xyz",
    "description" : "Alphabet Inc is a provider of internet content products and portals. Its suite of brands includes Search, Android, YouTube, Apps, Maps & Ads.",
    "ceo" : "Larry Page",
    "sector" : "Technology",
    "image" : "https://financialmodelingprep.com/images-New-jpg/GOOG.jpg"
  }
}
```

I am trying to use this API for an application I am creating so that users can provide the symbol in the route and the fuction takes the symbol as an argument to make the GET request as seen below:

```
@app.route('/stock/profile/<string:symbol>')
def get_jsonparsed_data(symbol):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)
    print(data)
url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/{}?apikey=yourApiKeyWouldGoHere".format(symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. It was the placement of the variables 'url' that needed changing. I needed to move the variable url to be the first variable inside the runction:

from flask import Flask
try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import json

## instatiating the Flask Class. "**name**" references the name of the current module being worked with which is hello-world.py

app = Flask(**name**)

@app.route('/stock/profile/')
def get_jsonparsed_data(symbol): 
    **url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/{}?apikey=5df07fe2e77eb907f2496af6f4a48260".format(symbol)**

```
response = urlopen(url)
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
return json.loads(data)
```